# Illustrator files created and exported on Mac look stretched on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, pdf, adobe-illustrator

Hopefully someone knows what's going on here. A file created in illustrator on Mac then exported to PDF or PNG looks stretched when viewed on Windows!

I can't find any settings for aspect ratio etc, I know there must be a solution, but I just can't find anything at all.

cheers!

Comment: What are you using to view the file? How does it look stretched? Is it actually stretched or is it a display issue?

Comment: I have a PDF which im just using adobe acrobat reader - problem seems to be happening on every windows pc ive tried.... its like the aspect ratio is wrong, like someone took a nice picture, grabbed it at both ends and just pulled - i thought it might be a display issue, except it happens on multiple PCs... i dont think its actually stretched, just the interpretation on non-macs is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently and came across this post trying to solve it. Eventually I discovered the underlying problem. My Windows machine's Display settings had been configured to use a resolution which did not match the monitor's native resolution. This caused everything to be stretched on the windows machine but I had never noticed it before moving a piece of precise artwork between my machines. I suspect this was the problem for you as well.

Research your display's native resolution (start by looking for the model number on the back of the display or use your laptop model number if on a laptop). Then change the Windows display settings to use that resolution.

Comment: Cheers mate! Been a while and I have no idea where these files went anymore.... I threw all my windows machines out and problem solved!